# PHP cURL submit JSP website form

Tags: php, forms, jsp, curl

Alright, I know this has been asked plenty of times, however my experience with cURL has been very touch and go, and I just haven't quite found the answer to my problem and been able to make it work.

Basic scenario: I am attempting to check reservation availability from Hyatt.com through a PHP script which I'll have run through cron, so I'll be alerted given x variables which I will set later. First step is to be able to generate a response to see the available room types after inputting Hotel, Check-In, and Check-Out dates. Here is where I'm struggling:

```
<?php

$url='http://www.hyatt.com/hyatt/index.jsp';
$hotel='Park Hyatt Paris-Vendome';
$checkin='Oct / 29 / 2014';
$checkout='Oct / 30 / 2014';

$ch = curl_init() ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );

$data = array(
    'searchTerms' => "$hotel",
    'check-in-date' => "$checkin",
    'check-out-date' => "$checkout",
    'find_hotel' => 'submit'
);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
$output = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo "$output\n";

?>
```

Now the form looks like the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="/hyatt/index.jsp?_DARGS=/hyatt/GlobalQuickbook.jsp.quickbookForm" name="quickbookForm" id="quickbookForm">    <input type="hidden" value="UTF-8" name="_dyncharset"></input><input type="hidden" value="-4660292374176517060" name="_dynSessConf"></input>
<div class='destinationField'><div id='destinationDefaultPlaceHolder' class='hide'>
City, attraction, address, or airport
</div>
<label for="searchTerms" class='heading'>Destination</label>
<input size="25" type="text" autocomplete="off" onclick="clearDefaultSearch(this);" value="City, attraction, address, or airport" tabindex="1" name="/booking/QuickbookHolder.location" maxlength="100" id="searchTerms"><input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:/booking/QuickbookHolder.location">
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>var arrivalDateSelected=dateFormatStyle;</script>
<div id='dateSelector' class='dateSelector'>
<ul class='date_selector_ul'>
<li class='label_container'>
<label for="check-in-date">Arrive</label>
</li>
<li class='input_container'>
<input type="hidden" id="check-in-date_hidden" value='MMM / DD / YYYY'/>
<input size="14" type="text" class="date-pick dp-applied" value="MMM / DD / YYYY" tabindex="2" name="/booking/QuickbookHolder.arrivalDate" id="check-in-date"><input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:/booking/QuickbookHolder.arrivalDate">
</li>
<li class='label_container'>
<label for="check-out-date">Depart</label>
</li>
<li class='input_container'>
<input type="hidden" id="check-out-date_hidden" value='MMM / DD / YYYY'/>
<input size="14" type="text" class="date-pick dp-applied" value="MMM / DD / YYYY" tabindex="3" name="/booking/QuickbookHolder.departureDate" id="check-out-date"><input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:/booking/QuickbookHolder.departureDate">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<button type="submit" tabindex='4' onclick="sendAjaxCall('quickbookForm','en'); mboxTrack('FindHotels_Button_Track'); return false;">Find Hotels</button>
<input type="hidden" value="submit" name="/atg/userprofiling/ReservationFormHandler.findHotels" id="find_hotel"><input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:/atg/userprofiling/ReservationFormHandler.findHotels">
</div>
```

However despite several attempts and changes to properly address the action instead of going to index.jsp I cannot for the life of me get this to function properly. I've given this a go for multiple days and sat on it to see if anything came to me, but as I've had no luck I figured I'd ask for some support. Yes, I have researched this, and yes I've seen similar issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835283/why-cant-i-submit-form-php-curl) but I just can't seem to quite get it to function and follow correctly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're trying to to submit that form in the upper right on [this page](http://www.hyatt.com/hyatt/index.jsp), that will be somewhat difficult. The form is a lot more complex then your above HTML. In first glance I also noted there is some XSS protection in there (_dynSessConf). You'll have to collect the tokens and send them with the POST request.

Comment: @Ambidex - Correct, that's what I was worried about. Suggestions on how to move forward on this?

Comment: I'd love to help you out be investigating further, but sadly, even only investigating could take a lot more time that I have to spare. But I'd suggest your first step would be trying to construct the POST request manually (through curl in command line) and see if you can reconstruct it thoroughly enough to get your expected results. So, get the tokens by requesting the formm first, then use the tokens (and all additional data) in your manual POST request. Without testing that first, there's no way telling if there are any other security implications. Hope that this made any sense.